# pass Functions to main method Arguments

Tags: c#, function, args

I have just started learning c# and need some help please
I have a task that i need to declare 2 functions to add/subtract and needs to be passed through to main method [args], idea is in cmd i can press 1 or 2 to pass on a particular method.
I then need to return the value to a new function.

## this is what i have done so far

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace addSubtractProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length >0)
            {
                if (args[0] =="1")
                    Console.WriteLine("You are using the Add Function" + );
            }
            else if (args[0] =="2")
                    Console.WriteLine("You are using the Minus Function");
         }
        int x =10, y =5;
        int z = addTwoNumbers(x, y);
        int i= minusTwoNumber(x,y);                                              

       //function Add Two Numbers
        static int addTwoNumbers (int a, int b)
            return (a + b);

          //function Minus Two Numbers
        static int minusTwoNumber (int a, int b)
            return (a - b);

}





    }
```

Comment: you should add c# to the tags, because this might attract the right people

Comment: shouldn't you use args[1] and args[2] instead of assigning static values ? And the call to addTwoNumbers and minusTwoNumbers should go into the if branch. Please remove the empty lines from your code.

Comment: i am try base it on what i learnt today based on this
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // command line agruments
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                if (args[0] == "1")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Do something");
                }
                else if (args[0] == "2")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Do something else");
                }

            }

Comment: How are your add/subtract funtions defined? You already have an add and subtract method within your program, but you dont call them when you check your first argument in the static void Main(string[] ). If you really need to have an external piece of code that is getting called by this programm, you need to create a new console application for each method and call that app from this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class DelegatesTest
    {
        delegate int ComputeFunctionCallback( int x, int y );

        public static void Run()
        {
            string input = "";
            Console.Write( "Press 1 or 2:" ); input = Console.ReadLine();

            if ( input != "" )
            {
                ComputeFunctionCallback compute = null;

                switch ( input )
                {
                    case "1":
                        Console.WriteLine( "You are using the Add Function" );
                        compute = Add;
                        break;

                    case "2":
                        Console.WriteLine( "You are using the Subtract Function" );
                        compute = Subtract;
                        break;
                }

                Console.WriteLine( "Result is {0}", compute( 5, 2 ) );
            }
        }


        static int Add( int a, int b )
        {
            return ( a + b );
        }

        static int Subtract( int a, int b )
        {
            return ( a - b );
        }
    }
```